# The device is not ready error when opening Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I get the error "The device is not ready" when I open visual studio, and also when I try to interact with TFS (check in, get latest, etc.)

[image]

I have tried the following to correct the issue with no luck in resolving it:

- Reboot
- Repair Visual Studio
- Uninstall/Reinstall Visual Studio

What device is not ready?  How can I make it ready or otherwise correct this error?  I'd prefer to not reinstall my OS, but I will if I need to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is (mostly) caused when the location your workspace is pointed to is no longer available.

All you need to do is reset the workspace 
(

- open sourcecontrol,
- in the toolbar click on the dropdownlist workspaces,
- edit the workspace of the computer the drive changed
- set the local folder to the correct location

)

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this sort of thing can be caused by a no-longer-accessible drive.  Here's something to try: Clear out your Most Recently Used project and file lists:

1. Run `regedit`.
2. Navigate to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectMRUList`.
3. Delete all the "File" items (File1, File2, File3, etc.).
4. Navigate to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\FileMRUList`.
5. Delete all the "File" items (File1, File2, File3, etc.).

If that doesn't work, have a look through the other items in 11.0 and under it, looking for no-longer-valid directories.  Here are some other nodes to look under:

- 11.0
- 11.0\External Tools
- Find (might have a directory specified for find-in-files)
- JavaScriptLanguageService
- Keyboard
- NewProjectDialog and subnodes

...and there are probably several others, but at this point I got bored with looking.  Anyway, look through the various nodes for a network location or removable drive that doesn't exist anymore, and get rid of that path or point that path elsewhere, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I did recently have a drive fail.  I repaired it, and the drive letter did change, although none of my projects were stored on it, and VS itself wasn't on it.

Comment: Clearing those entries in the registry didn't fix the issue, but changing the drive letter for my secondary HDD (the one that failed) back to its original letter cleared up this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @KyleTrauberman, another thing you might try is running [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and then running VS 2012 to see if you can determine exactly what's opening that drive.  You could also search the registry for references to that drive ("H:" or whatever) to see if you find things pointing to it.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a HDD fail, which I managed to repair.  In doing so, the drive letter changed.  I changed the letter of the drive back to its original letter designation, and this issue no longer occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.   I had clicked the button that was asking me to upgrade to a local workspace.  After I did that I was getting the 'device not ready error' anytime I tried to do anything with TFS.   The response marked as an answer did not help me.   I had to completely remove the workspace (via the menu described in Olivier's answer) and then re-add a new workspace.